# Pre-populate a ReactJS form with data when user clicks an object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I want to pre-populate a form with data like a user's account profile or something. I can't figure out the right way to do this.

- Using React and Redux
- When I change the properties it should update the object currently selected
- When I click an object it's properties should update a form with it's values that is in view (Couldn't figure out)

Any simple example would help me out a bunch!

What I'm trying to build (I built with Vuejs:

[image]

Comment: Is there a specific bit of functionality and code you are trying and its not working? If so could you post that here? It kind of sounds like you just want general information on building a full React/Redux app. There are a buuunch of tutorials on this. Start with React and really understand the unidirectional data flow. Facebook's tutorial is decent. Then move on to handling application state with Redux. Here is a list of many great tutorials: https://github.com/xgrommx/awesome-redux. The creator of Redux also made a video series: https://egghead.io/series/getting-started-with-redux

Comment: @AndyNoelker Maybe I'm just rushing into, hard knowing Angular really well and then starting from nothing.